# Why can't I lauch Unity Tweak Tool

Tags: unity-tweak-tool

I tried to launch the Unity Tweak tool, which had been working fine before, and it wouldn't work at all. When I do it from the terminal, I get this:

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ unity-tweak-tool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool", line 72, in <module>
    UnityTweakTool.Application()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    executable_name=cmd_old.split('\x00')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys were right, but I didn't know what to do. I copied and pasted this instead
[https://launchpadlibrarian.net/163835720/**init**.py](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/163835720/__init__.py)

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to **init**.py file and edit the file

Comment file from line 79 to 89

It worked for me!

Comment: I am not very experianced so you might have to spell a few things out from me. LIke where is the file and what do you mean by Comment from line 79 to 89

Comment: nano /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py


Go to line 79 and comment till 89.

Comment: What do you mean by comment, I can open the file.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It says: "`list index out of range`". So, you could change 1 to 2:
 1. `executable_name=cmd_old.split('\x00')[1]`  //Change it
 2. `executable_name=cmd_old.split('\x00')[0]`  //to this

---

In order, to do that open terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py
```

Then, go to line 79, `executable_name=cmd_old.split('\x00')[1]` will be there.

**Good luck!**

Comment: Where do you suggest to change it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please, take a look at it.